# JDBC beans configuration

Tags: java, database, jdbc, javabeans

I was following the tutorial from

http://www.mkyong.com/spring/maven-spring-jdbc-example/

I have not worked with beans before and one thing from this tutorial puzzled me

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <bean id="customerDAO" class="com.mkyong.customer.dao.impl.JdbcCustomerDAO">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    </beans>
```

This is a bean file which contains a bean which sets the dataSource variable from JDBCCustomerDao to be dataSource which is yet another bean contained in this file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mkyongjava" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />
</bean>
```

I understand so far that the dataSource variable from JdbcCustomerDao is set to have the properties

```
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mkyongjava" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />
```

However I'm not sure what the url points to. Is is the url where my database can be found? Is it the directory which I can create dbs in?

Probably this question has a pretty simple answer but I'm not that sure and google searches didn't really help.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

JDBC urls are driver-specific. In this case, it points to a MySQL server at localhost, port 3306, to the database named `mkyongjava`.

Comment: why does it have a "jdbc:mysql://" before the link? Should't it be localhost:3306/mkyongjava.sql ?

Comment: Nope. The URL you gave me has an implied http:// protocol prefix. Anyway, the first part must be jdbc: , then comes the JDBC driver selection (in your case mysql: ), then comes the driver-specific part, which the MySQL driver interprets as a host & port for a TCP connection, and the database to connect to as the URL path.